# Prove that $\sin(n x) + \sin((n+2) x) = 2\cos(x)\sin((n+1) x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I need to prove that $\sin(n x) + \sin((n+2) x) = 2\cos(x)\sin((n+1) x)$. I have already checked that this is correct for $n=1$ and $n=2$, but I'm not able to prove this identity by induction. Now I was thinking of making a shift to the imaginary numbers by saying : $\sin(nx) + \sin((n+2) x) = Im\{e^{i n x}(1 + e^{2ix})$, but I have no clue how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the formula
$$\sin(A) + \sin(B) = 2 \cos((B-A)/2) \sin((A+B)/2)$$

Comment: It is that simple?? what is the name of this identity? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is any name associated with this identity. You may try googling for sum of sines formula.

Comment: Prosthaphaeresis formulas. Or Simpson's formulas, most of the time : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: Many tables nowadays list these as the "sum-to-product" formulas.  (Prosthaphaeresis is what people used before the introduction of logarithms, if you can imagine...)

Answer (score 1):

Use the addition theorem
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha \cos\beta + \cos\alpha \sin\beta$$
This implies
$$\sin(\alpha-\beta) + \sin(\alpha+\beta) = 2\sin\alpha \cos\beta$$
Now set $\alpha = (n+1)x$, $\beta = x$.